# Joint probability question and conditional density function

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a gamma random variable with parameters $\alpha=2$ and
>   $\beta={1\over8}$ and given $X$ the random variable $Y$ is uniformly
>   distributed between $2X$ and $8X$.
>
> a) Find $f(y)$ (density function of Y)
>
> b) Find $f(x|y=1)$

Now I found $f(y|x) = {1\over6X}$ and used it to find $f(x,y)=f(y|x)f(x)$ and obtained $f(x,y)=f(x)/6X = {64xe^{-8x}\over6X}$

And I integrated this with respect to x and obtained $f(y)={4\over3X}$ which seems to be a constant since it does not depend on y.

In part b, I found $f(x|y=1)={f(x,y)\over f(y=1)}=8xe^{-8x}$

I am not sure with this solution, I would be glad if you check.

Comment: You may want to redo your computations starting from the correct conditional density $$f(y\mid x)=\frac1{6x}\mathbf 1_{2x<y<8x}$$

Comment: Isn't $f(x|y)$ continuous? such that $f(x|y=1)=0$?